# Padding seems to be not working

Tags: css, padding

Padding seems to be not working. 
On hover, the padding comes out of the container. 
Can anyone tell me why this is happening? 
The padding must give white space between the menu but it's not , instead on hover the padding comes out of the container.

http://ashwin931996.webege.com

Comment: Give a `padding:32px;` in `#nav ul { }`

Comment: please reproduce in a fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Con't understand what are you trying to achive...
Anyway, what if you add to the nav a:hover this:

```
display: inline-block
```

Is this the effect you wanted?

Answer (score -1):

hai one small mistake in css u change this its work perfectly.
this as follows ;

```
#nav a {
color: #000000;
padding: 0 20px 0 30px;
text-decoration: none;
}

#nav a:hover {
padding: 0 20px 0 30px;
}
```

Comment: :hover inherits, no need to declare padding again

Answer (score -1):

well had to rewrite some part of your CSS and the padding is actually there is you but you needed to give the a tag a display: block ; but once i did this it muddle up everything so i had clean up the mess i made. hope you like it. P.S this was tested in Mozilla firefox might wanna try it out in other browser.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "rbno2_light_alternative_Rg";
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    src: url("../fonts/rbno2light_a-webfont.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("../fonts/-webfont.woff") format("woff"), url("../fonts/rbno2light_a-webfont.ttf") format("truetype"), url("../fonts/rbno2light_a-webfont.svg#rbno2_light_alternative_Rg") format("svg");
}
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary, time, mark, audio, video {
    -x-system-font: none;
    border-bottom-color: -moz-use-text-color;
    border-bottom-style: none;
    border-bottom-width: 0;
    border-left-color-ltr-source: physical;
    border-left-color-rtl-source: physical;
    border-left-color-value: -moz-use-text-color;
    border-left-style-ltr-source: physical;
    border-left-style-rtl-source: physical;
    border-left-style-value: none;
    border-left-width-ltr-source: physical;
    border-left-width-rtl-source: physical;
    border-left-width-value: 0;
    border-right-color-ltr-source: physical;
    border-right-color-rtl-source: physical;
    border-right-color-value: -moz-use-text-color;
    border-right-style-ltr-source: physical;
    border-right-style-rtl-source: physical;
    border-right-style-value: none;
    border-right-width-ltr-source: physical;
    border-right-width-rtl-source: physical;
    border-right-width-value: 0;
    border-top-color: -moz-use-text-color;
    border-top-style: none;
    border-top-width: 0;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: inherit;
    font-size-adjust: inherit;
    font-stretch: inherit;
    font-style: inherit;
    font-variant: inherit;
    font-weight: inherit;
    line-height: inherit;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-top: 0;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style-image: none;
    list-style-position: outside;
    list-style-type: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after, q:before, q:after {
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
#logo {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 27%;
    width: 372px;
}
#logo h1 {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    display: block;
    font-family: rbno2_light_alternative_Rg;
    font-size: 2.5em;
    letter-spacing: 0.3em;
    padding-bottom: 2%;
    padding-left: 1%;
    padding-right: 2%;
    padding-top: 2%;
    width: 432px;
}
#nav {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 16%;
    width: 100%;
}
#nav ul {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    list-style-image: none;
    list-style-position: outside;
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 100%;
}
#nav ul li {
    color: #000000;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    font-family: rbno2_light_alternative_Rg;
    font-size: 1.9em;
}
#nav a {
    color: #000000;
    display: block;
    padding-bottom: 1em;
    padding-left: 3em;
    padding-right: 3em;
    padding-top: 1em;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#nav a:hover {
    background-color: #000000;
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: CSS with Mozilla-internal representation. please do not put that in your CSS

Comment: first try to give your li a block display and float of either left or right depending on how you want it aligned. And since you li didn't have an height, you should have given your a tag a display of block... and also  not tested in ie yet so you might want to do that

Comment: Mark why the down vote??? already commented telling the guy it only tested in Mozilla??

Comment: Tried, http://ashwin931996.webege.com/
But it does work locally, but not on the server

Comment: vote down, because you post invalid Mozilla-internal representation code. try to give a all-round solution. we don't want to go back to those days where there are buttons on a webpage "best viewed in ..."